# Javascript mouseover audio not playing in Safari

Tags: javascript, audio, safari, mouseover

I can't get my mouseover audio to play in Safari. It works in Chrome, ||Opera, Camino, Firefox and IE. I'm using this in the HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()" onclick="clicksound.playclip()" href="#">link/a>
```

With this javascript in my page footer:

```
<script>

// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
// Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for full source code

//** Usage: Instantiate script by calling: var uniquevar=createsoundbite("soundfile1",                 "fallbackfile2", "fallebacksound3", etc)
//** Call: uniquevar.playclip() to play sound

var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"mp4": "audio/mp4",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
"wav": "audio/wav"
}

function createsoundbite(sound){
var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
        sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
        if (arguments[i].match(/.(w+)$/i))
            sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
        html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
    }
    html5audio.load()
    html5audio.playclip=function(){
        html5audio.pause()
        html5audio.currentTime=0
        html5audio.play()
    }
    return html5audio
}
else{
    return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
}
}

//Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

var mouseoversound=createsoundbite("http://graphicviolence.co.uk/sounds/typewriter.ogg", "http://graphicviolence.co.uk/sounds/typewriter.mp3")
var clicksound=createsoundbite("http://graphicviolence.co.uk/sounds/bell.ogg", "http://graphicviolence.co.uk/sounds/bell.mp3")

</script>
```

Anybody know why Safari will not execute this? See my website at: http://graphicviolence.co.uk

Thanks
Tim, London

Comment: Which version of Safari are you testing with?

Comment: 5.1.7 - although I've asked other people to view in Safari and it has not worked in any of those either. Don't know what versions they are using, mine is fully up todate.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please share solution if you have found one.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the exact same script on my project , it works perfectly fine one both Chrome and Safari. But when it comes to iPhone and iPad Safari, it screwed up too. I have tested yours, it really doesn't work . 
Perhaps you may want to check on your script plug in